# Can std::string::resize() throw when shrinking?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring

Consider the following function:

```cpp
void shrink_string(std::string& str) {
  if (str.size() >= 2) {
    str.resize(str.size() - 2);
  }
}
```

I wonder if this function can be declared `noexcept` (assuming C++11 standard)? I understand that [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) does not declare `.resize()` as noexcept, but that's mostly because this method can be used both for growing and shrinking a string.

Obviously, shrinking can be trivially implemented by leaving the string's capacity constant and simply reducing the internal length; at the same time `resize()` may decide to reallocate anyways, in order to free up some memory -- but would it fall back to the trivial resizing if reallocation throws an error?

Comment: Is the intent also to reclaim the space?  Then `resize` won't do that.

Comment: I think pretty clearly the intent is to remove the last two characters of the string.  The space involved is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/):

> In case the container shrinks, all iterators, pointers and references to elements that have not been removed remain valid after the resize and refer to the same elements they were referring to before the call.

Therefore, resizing the vector to something smaller will not alter the memory (use `shrink_to_fit` instead to (suggest a) reduce capacity to the size). That's because there is no standard way in the OS to resize the memory and force the pointers to be the same.

[HeapReAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heaprealloc)() for example, in Windows, may or may not return the same pointer but you can't force it to return the same.

Comment: Thanks, but this is related to `std::vector`. I wonder if the same guarantees are available for `std::string`.

Comment: It's the same memory allocation strategy, so yes.

Comment: "that have not been removed" refers to elements at indices smaller than the new size, hence your conclusion is moot

Comment: So while this shows there's no *reason* for the resize to throw it doesn't guarentee that it cannot.